# Can this dragon from the Rise of Tiamat adventure fit in this area from Episode 2?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, creature-size, dragons, rise-of-tiamat

The main map of the area in Episode 2 ("The Sea of Moving Ice") contains effectively 2 floors: a series of hallways and rooms on the top floor, and a large cavern as the bottom floor.

> The dragon, Arauthator, is located on the bottom floor. Many times throughout the descriptions for rooms on the top floor, there are statements about kobolds raising an alarm. Can Arauthator fit in the hallways on the top floor?

The main hallways are about 15 feet wide.

> I'm not sure what kind of dangers the PCs really suffer if an alarm is raised unless Arauthator can come and attack them. I'm not sure if there is room, but I also don't think it makes a lot of sense to have a Trophy Room and such if Arauthator can't come up and see it.

Can the dragon fit?

Comment: Can you explain the problem? Isn't Arauthator huge, and thus 15 feet wide?

Comment: @goodguy5: Indeed. I'm confused by OP's point of confusion as well.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I just didn't realize how small a "huge" dragon was. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arauthator is Huge, and is 15x15 feet.

Any creature can squeeze into a space large enough to accommodate a creature one size smaller than itself. With 15x15 hallways he should be able to move freely through them. If the ceiling is 10 feet high, he couls squeeze into them. Any lower, however, and he would be unable to fit through.

> **Squeezing into a Smaller Space**
>
> A creature can squeeze through a space that is large
> enough for a creature one size smaller than it. Thus, a
> Large creature can squeeze through a passage that's
> only 5 feet wide. While squeezing through a space,
> a creature must spend 1 extra foot for every foot it
> moves there, and it has disadvantage on attack rolls
> and Dexterity saving throws. Attack rolls against the
> creature have advantage while it’s in the smaller space.

Comment: Where are you getting "gargantuan" from? Per [room 20](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/rot/the-sea-of-moving-ice#20ArauthatorsAbyss) (p. 36 of *Rise of Tiamat*, or p. 122 in the *Tyranny of Dragons* combined reprint), Arauthator is an [adult white dragon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/adult-white-dragon) - which is merely Huge, not Gargantuan. That said, Huge creatures can fit in 15-foot-wide hallways even without squeezing.

Answer (score 4):

## Arauthator can easily access these apertures

Arauthator is an "Adult White Dragon", which are Huge creatures, which are 15 feet big.

As you mentioned, the hallways are 15 feet, so there is no issue with a huge creature fitting into the space. Technically, even a gargantuan creature (20 feet) could fit into the space via the squeezing rules.